# Is it possible to download a file from server to my device having MGWT&GwtPhoneGap app?

Tags: gwt, cordova, download, mgwt

I developed an app using MGWT and GwtPhoneGap and I used rpc for server communication. I want to download a file from server to my client device(iOs/android).is this possible? if so what
I need to do to achieve my goal?. I'm not getting great support from MGWT forums. Please tell me the way to do it.

thanks in Advance

I put some effort on my question, I've done like this. but still not succeeded. please go through my code.

```
public final native String download(String serverUrl,String filepath,Callback callback)
  /*-{
return this.download(serverUrl, filePath, function(result) {
callback.Callback::o:onSuccess(Result;);)(result);
}, function(error) {
 callback.Callback::o:onError(Error;);)(error);
});
  }-*/;
```

Answer (score 3):

If the file is a simple file (A PDF for exemple)
Just put a link to the file URL, the mobile navigator will download the file to the phone.
If the file is generated, you must create a servlet for doing the download :

```
public class ServletDownloadDemo extends HttpServlet{

  private static final int BYTES_DOWNLOAD = 1024;

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                     "attachment;filename=downloadname.txt");
    ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
    InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/testing.txt");

    int read=0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){
        os.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close(); 
   }
}
```

In GWT for a Post Request, you can use th FormPanel which will send the request to an hidden iframe.

```
FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
form.setAction("/downloadServlet");
FlowPanel hiddenPanel = new FlowPanel();
hiddenPanel.add(new Hidden("name1", "value"));
hiddenPanel.add(new Hidden("name2", "value"));
form.setWidget(hiddenPanel);
RootPanel.get().add(form);
form.submit();
```

Or you can put a real form.

But with PhoneGap, you can use the [File API](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/FileModule), but you must ask to the user where write the file in his phone. You can download the file content via a RPC request if you want, and write to the file.

Comment: Hidden forms are often used by Js developpers, but with GWT the most appropriate way to fire POST requests is by using a RequestBuilder. Hopefully HTML5, websockets and GWT-like technologies will get us rid of having to use such hacks. +1 for the file API though.

Comment: Yes I know, but a RequestBuilder will not download the file, The FormPanel will send the POST request and download the file from the Servlet automatically.

Comment: I see... He wants to download the file, not display it. You're right +1.

Comment: I want to download the file with out asking client.For this I used depended on phonegap. I've done like this,But still not succeeded..              public final native String download(String serverUrl,String filepath,Callback callback)
   /*-{
   return this.download(serverUrl, filePath, function(result) {
    callback.Callback::o:onSuccess(Result;);)(result);
    }, function(error) {
     callback.Callback::o:onError(Error;);)(error);
    });
  }-*/;

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just wrote a servlet which will provide the file.

From then on you have two choices:

- Put a link in your app and redirect a user to the url which will be caught by the servlet.
- For POST requests use a [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) (not hidden forms !), then write the response to a new window using JSNI.

  ```
  private native void openWindow(String contents, String blockedMsg) /*-{
          var win = window.open("", "_blank");
          if (win && win.top) {
              win.document.write(contents);
          } else {
              alert(blockedMsg);
          }
  }-*/;
  ```